# Indexing 1d array with values in a 2d array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, lua

I have an array, `tiles`, which contains tiles in a tileset. I also have a 15x10 2 dimensional array, `room`, which has numbers corresponding to the tiles in `tiles`. What I'm having trouble with is this:

```
room = { ... }       -- 15x10 2d array
csv = require("csv") -- load a csv file, not relevant to the problem
file = csv.open("room/room-0.0.csv")
row = 1
for fields in file:lines() do
    for col, val in ipairs(fields) do
        room[row][col] = val
    end
    row = row + 1
end
-- room looks something like this:
-- { {1, 4, 2, 3, 2, ...},
--   ...
--   {3, 3, 2, 4, 2, ...} }
```

All is well at this point. Here is where things go wrong though:

```
tiles = {"banana", "apple", "orange", "pitaya"}
for i, j in ipairs(room) do            -- looping through room
    print("-------")
    for k, tilenum in ipairs(j) do     -- tilenum = room[i][k]
        print(tiles[tilenum])          -- tiles[room[k][i]]
    end                                -- tiles[tilenum] == nil
end
```

The output:

```
-------
nil
nil
nil
nil
nil
...
```

What should happen:

```
-------
banana
pitaya
apple
orange
apple
...
```

Note: Though the objects actually in `tiles` are not printable, I have tried this example with numbers, strings, etc. They don't work.

Comment: "*All is well at this point.*" How? `ipairs` requires a table, but the result from `file:lines()` is a sequence of *strings*.

Comment: @NicolBolas `file:lines()` returns a table, since it's opened by `csv` instead of a normal `io.open()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not showing the value of `tilenum`, but I suspect that even if it's a number, it's in a string form, and when indexing Lua tables, `"1"` index is not the same as `1` index (and that's probably why your `tiles[tilenum]` returns `nil`).

You need to check the `val` values you assign (that later become `tilenum`) and if they are indeed numbers, then change `= val` to `= tonumber(val)`.

Comment: You are correct, `val` was a string. Adding `tonumber(val)` fixed it. Thanks